# Redirecting output for find & exec to a log file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, output

I created a script for moving the files based on the below reference. I am trying to capture all the files activity that are picked up and moved from source to destination along with any unsuccessful files.
**I tried pipping** the output to a log file, but after operation the log file size is 0. Any recommendations please?

Reference Doc#
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59112/preserve-directory-structure-when-moving-files-using-find

Below is the code block

```
destination=$(cd -- "$destination" && pwd)
cd -- "$source" &&
find . -type f -newermt $startdays -not -newermt $enddays -exec sh -c '
  for x do
    mkdir -p "$0/${x%/*}"
    mv "$x" "$0/$x"
  done
' "$destination" {} + >> output.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `mv` does not produce any output.  If you want it to produce output, try `mv -v`.

Comment: thank you, that worked fine. When I run my script test1.sh, it prints out mv:cannot move messages for unsuccessful files (: Permission denied) on to the console . I want to capture these reject files to a separate log file as well. I am thinking of writing a wrapper shell Main.sh and call test1.sh from it and redirect the output of this to another log file. Any better suggestion?

Comment: Just redirect stderr: `find ... >> output.log 2>&1`